# How to use bit-addressable in java?

Tags: java

How to use bit-addresable(assembly) in java?

e.g.

```
int a = 13;
int b = 99;
//How can i write 13 & 99 (but & only last bit of 13,99 = 1 & 1)?
//In assembly you can use Acc.0 or anything.x to manipulate bit.
//How to use this feature in java?
```

Comment: @biziclop, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a = 99;
int b = 11;
int q = a & b & 0x1;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no special syntax for this operation, direct bit manipulation is simply not that crucial in Java as it is in assembly.

You can always use masking to achieve the same effect and there is the [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class, which lets you do all kinds of bit manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
(a & b) & 0x01
```